# Parallel prefix adder cells in Negabinary

Tags: digital-logic, adder

I'm trying to design a parallel prefix adder for a negabinary based adder. Negabinary is base \$-2\$ instead of the familiar base \$2\$ binary. Each 1 bit adder generates a sum and two (instead of one in binary) carries that go to the next adder.

To make the adder faster, I want to use a parallel prefix structure, like the Ladner-Fischer structure given below. I'm familiar with the functionality of the purple cell in the binary system, but I'm unsure how I could get the same functionality in the negabinary system.

The reason I'm doing this is just for fun, I haven't found any uses for negabinary yet.

*Formulas for calculating the sum and carries:*

\$s_i = a_i \oplus b_i \oplus (c_i^+ + c_i^-) \$

\$ c_{i+1}^+ = \overline{a_i}\overline{b_i}\overline{c_i^+}c_i^- \$

\$ c_{i+1}^- = a_ib_i\overline{c_i^-}+a_i c_i^+ \overline{c_i^-}+b_i c_i^+ \overline{c_i^-} \$

*Ladner-fischer carry tree structure:*

[image]

If anything is unclear, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: While this may be an interesting question, it doesn't seem to be an electrical question, and you may have better luck taking it to the math SE.

Comment: I put it here because I think EE people have more experience with carry logic, designing adders etc.

Comment: This is totally an EE question

Comment: Seems like you need more than two outputs per carry.  Don't you need generate and propagate for both carry and borrow?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the Ladner-fischer structure. It was just an example to show off a parallel prefix tree. Each 1 bit negabinary adder outputs a sum, a positive and a negative carry. I'm unsure if we can use the concepts of generate and propagate with negabinary.

Comment: conversion from negbinary to binary is adding 1010101010101010 and then xor with 101010101010101010, that may be useful.

Comment: I’m afraid there’s something wrong with your formulas. As I understand it, with base \$-2\$, the sum at position \$i\$ needs 2 carry bits: 1 at position \$i+1\$ and 1 at position \$i+2\$. With 4 input bits at a given position, the mathematical sum may be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, which is written, in base \$-2\$, 000, 001, 110, 111 or 100. You might want to design a 5-input “full-adder-like” cell that still has 3 ouputs, to ease the design of your adder.

Answer (score 1):

I have probably spent more time on this question than I should've, but here are my findings.

I cannot find any example of a "pure" parallel prefix adder for negabinary numbers. I also think it's an open problem, as I haven't seen any proof that it *isn't* possible.

The closest I can get you is by using a two-step negative negabinary addition (commonly abbreviated n.n.b.a. in literature). It is based on the following property:

Let \$f(x) = \overline{x_{n-1}}x_{n-2}...\overline{x_1}x_0\$ and \$g(x) = x_{n-1}\overline{x_{n-2}}...x_1\overline{x_0}\$. These are basically an XOR-operation with `0xAA...AA` and `0x55...55` respectively.
You can then prove that

$$-(a +_{nb} b) = g\left(f(a) + f(b) + 1\right)$$

Where the left side is the negabinary sum \$+_{nb}\$, while the \$+\$ on the right side is a normal binary sum.

The negative sum can then simply be inverted using the same property but with a zero operand:

$$-x = g\left(f(x) + f(0) + 1\right)$$

So in order to find the sum using parallel prefix adders, you can:

1. Compute \$f(a)\$ and \$f(b)\$, ie. by inverting every odd bit of the negabinary numbers
2. Compute the regular binary sum while setting the carry bit for the LSB (the \$+1\$), leading to a first intermediary sum \$s_1\$.
3. Invert all bits of \$s_1\$ (this is \$f(g(s_1))\$). This is the finish of the first sum, while also starting the inversion.
4. Increment the result by `0xAA...AB` (\$=f(0)+1\$) using a parallel prefix adder, yielding the second intermediary sum \$s_2\$
5. Compute \$g(s_2)\$ (inverting each even bit) to find the final negabinary sum.

---

I have actually tried to find a "pure" parallel prefix adder, but I considered it too complex for the time I was willing to spend on it. Here's why:

The whole point of parallel prefix adders is to find some operation of \$\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n\$ that allows you to easily calculate the (in this case 2) carries from these bits. As an added constraint, the operation needs to be *associative* to be computed in parallel. For example, this basically excludes any NOT operator (that is not part of a double negation). For example: \$a \circ b=a\cdot \bar b\$ is not an associative operator, because

$$\begin{align}
(a\circ b)\circ c &= a\cdot \bar b \cdot \bar c\\
a\circ (b \circ c) &= a\cdot \overline{b \cdot \bar c}
\end{align}$$

Note that the boolean operator for the carries in your question includes the mixed terms \$c_i^+\overline{c_i^-}\$ and \$c_i^-\overline{c_i^+}\$, making it impossible to use it as-is. For a single carry in normal binary addition, it became quite obvious how to construct this operator when thinking about it in terms of *generation* and *propagation*, but it seems to be not so obvious for negabinary carries.

Comment: My current understanding is that it is in fact impossible to construct this "pure" parallel prefix adder. It would seem that a parallel prefix adder can get an efficiency of O(log(N)), whereas a negabinary equivalent seems to always have complexity O(2*log(N)) (2x n.n.b.a).

Comment: I didn't find any literature proving or stating that it was *impossible*. I'd be happy to be proven wrong either way though. But the 2-step n.n.b.a. does seem to be the standard currently for negabinary addition as far as I can tell.